# python game: lives_left drops too fast and game is over unexpectedly

Tags: pygame

1. Introduction: Different letters fall down from the top of the screen after a time interval and the letter will vanish while you strike the corresponding key on the keyboard. The x position of each letter is random. Game is over when more than 10 letters have reached the bottom.
2. Progress:I have implemented some functions such as generating random falling letters and eliminating letters by striking the corresponding keys.
3. Problem: Game should be over when more than 10 letters had reached the bottom. However, after running the codes, game is immediately over while the first falling letter has reached the bottom. I suppose there's something wrong with 'check_letter_bottom()' method in game_functions.py since it is observed that lives_left drops quickly from 10 to 0. What corrections should I make?

Here are my codes:

1. alphabet_zoo.py

```
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *
from settings import Settings
import game_functions as gf
from game_stats import GameStats

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    az_settings =Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), RESIZABLE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alphabet Zoo")
    stats = GameStats(az_settings)
    letters = pygame.sprite.Group()
    start = time.time()
    sleepTime = 3


    while True:
        now = time.time()
        gf.check_events(letters)
        if stats.game_active:
            print(stats.lives_left)
            letters.update()
            gf.update_screen(az_settings, stats, screen, letters)
            if now - start >sleepTime:
                gf.letter_generator(az_settings ,screen, letters)
                start = now


run_game()
```

2. settings.py

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bg_color = (0, 0, 0)
        self.letter_speed_factor = 10
        self.lives_limit = 10
```

3. game_functions.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from letter import Letter

def letter_generator(az_settings, screen, letters):
    new_letter = Letter(az_settings, screen)
    letters.add(new_letter)

def check_events(letters):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            for ltr in letters:
                if ltr.ascii == event.key:
                    letters.remove(ltr)

def letter_fallen(stats):
    if stats.lives_left > 0:
        stats.lives_left -= 1
    else:
        stats.game_active = False

def check_letter_bottom(screen, letters, stats):
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    for ltr in letters.sprites():
        if ltr.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:    # there might be some problems
            letter_fallen(stats)


def update_screen(az_settings, stats, screen, letters):
    screen.fill(az_settings.bg_color)
    check_letter_bottom(screen, letters, stats)
    letters.draw(screen)
    letters.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

4. letter.py

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Letter(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, az_settings, screen):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.az_settings = az_settings
        a = random.randint(97, 123)
        c = chr(a)
        name = c.upper() + '.png'
        b = 'images/' + name
        print(b)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(b)
        self.ascii = a

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0, self.screen_rect.right)
        self.rect.top = self.screen_rect.top
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)



    def update(self):
        if self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.rect.centery += self.az_settings.letter_speed_factor
```

5. game_stats.py

```
class GameStats():
    def __init__(self, az_settings):
        self.az_settings = az_settings
        self.reset_stats()
        self.game_active = True

    def reset_stats(self):
        self.lives_left = self.az_settings.lives_limit
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, so it's a little hard to figure out what's going on.

That being said, looks like you might not be removing the letters after they damage the player, so they damage the player every frame once they're below the line?

Comment: I wish the letters that have reached the bottom remain there, so although it works if `letters.remove(ltr)` is added before `letter_fallen(stats)` in game_functions.py, that is an imperfect solution.

Comment: You could add a field to the letter so that they keep track of whether or not they have damaged the player, and make your if statement that checks if they're below the line check that as well.

Comment: @The Zach Man No letter that has reached the bottom line should be removed. It just stays there. however, the lives_left should be subtracted by 1 at the same time. Game is over when lives_left drops to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the letters after scoring them, you could remove them from the `letters` group and add them to a different group.

So in your `run_game()` function, add `scored_letters = pygame.sprite.Group()`.

Then in `check_letter_bottom(…)`

```
def check_letter_bottom(screen, letters, scored_letters, stats):
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    for ltr in letters.sprites():
        if ltr.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom: 
            letter_fallen(stats)
            letters.remove(ltr)
            scored_letters.add(ltr)
```

Then include `scored_letters.draw(screen)` in `update_screen(…)`. Probably before `letters.draw()` so falling letters are on top.

Comment: Yeah that's a way to implement the functions, but I have a much easier way as below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it is actually simple to solve my problem by adding `ltr.rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom` before `letter_fallen(stats)` and making a little change of the if statement(> instead of >=). It's like this:

```
def check_letter_bottom(screen, letters, stats):
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    for ltr in letters.sprites():
        if ltr.rect.bottom > screen_rect.bottom:    
            ltr.rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom
            letter_fallen(stats)
```